# xpath: check if current elements position is second in order

Tags: xpath

**Background:**
I have an XML document with the following structure:

```
<body>
<section>content</section>
<section>content</section>
<section>content</section>
<section>content</section>
</body>
```

Using xpath I want to check if a `<section>` element is the second element and if so apply some function.

**Question:**
How do I check if a `<section>` element is the second element in the body element?

```
../section[position()=2]
```

Comment: Does it have to be a filter? How about `(/section)[2]`, ie. select explicitly the second section?

Comment: Yes, it has to be a filter. (/section)[2] does not work...

Comment: I found a solution. It is NOT pretty (so it will not post it) but in this case it is good enugh.

Comment: @user2075124 Please look at my annswer

Answer (score 0):

> Question: How do I check if a  element is the second element
>   in the body element?

Using C#,  you can utilize the`XPathNodeIterator` class in order to traverse the nodes data, and use its `CurrentPosition` property to investigate the current node position:

```
XPathNodeIterator.CurrentPosition
```

Example:

```
const string xmlStr = @"<body>
                            <section>1</section>
                            <section>2</section>
                            <section>3</section>
                            <section>4</section>
                        </body>";

using (var stream = new StringReader(xmlStr))
{
    var document = new XPathDocument(stream);
    XPathNavigator navigator = document.CreateNavigator();

    XPathNodeIterator nodes = navigator.Select("/body/section");
    if (nodes.MoveNext())
    {
        XPathNavigator nodesNavigator = nodes.Current;

        XPathNodeIterator nodesText =
            nodesNavigator.SelectDescendants(XPathNodeType.Text, false);

        while (nodesText.MoveNext())
        {
            if (nodesText.CurrentPosition == 2)
            {
                //DO SOMETHING WITH THE VALUE AT THIS POSITION
                var currentValue = nodesText.Current.Value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know if the second element in the `body` is named `section` then you can do this:

```
local-name(/body/child::element()[2]) eq "section"
```

That will return either `true` or `false`.

However, you then asked how can you check this and if it is `true`, then apply some function. In XPath you cannot author your own functions you can only do that in XQuery or XSLT. So let me for a moment assume you are wishing to call a different XPath function on the value of the second element if it is a `section`. Here is an example of applying the `lower-case` function:

```
if(local-name(/body/child::element()[2]) eq "section")then
    lower-case(/body/child::element()[2])
else()
```

However, this can simplified as lower-case and many other functions take a value with a minimum cardinality of zero. This means that you can just apply the function to a path expression, and if the path did not match anything then the function typically returns an empty sequence, in the same way as a path that did not match will. So, this is semantically equivalent to the above:

```
lower-case(/body/child::element()[2][local-name(.) eq "section"])
```

If you are in XQuery or XSLT and are writing your own functions, I would encourage you to write functions that will accept a minimum cardinality of zero, just like `lower-case` does. By doing this you can chain functions together, and if there is no input data (i.e. from a path expression that does not match anything), these is no output data. This leads to a very nice functional programming style.